# Html table look collapsing in some browsers

Tags: html, html-table

I have a problem with dynamic height of the table cell. I've set it to `rowspan=2` so it should take 2 rows for it's height.

My code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 640px;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img src="bg-top.png" /></td>
    </tr>   
<tr style="height: 669px;">
    <td><img src="bg-left.png" style="display: block"/></td>
    <td valign="top" rowspan=2 >
     lorem ipsu
    </td>
    <td><img align="right" src="bg-right.png" style="display: block"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td background="cont.png"></td>
<td background="cont.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to make images look like a border around the text, and if text is longer than what can be put in 700px than it should repeat `cont.png`. It looks fine in Opera and Chrome but in IE and Firefox it's not working.

Screnshots:

- in mozzila: http://shrani.si/f/1h/12j/3c72q2gv/notworking.png
- in chrome: http://shrani.si/f/Q/n/3w7G0jOn/working.png

Any ideas what I might change?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. That's not their intended use. Tables were meant for data which is best suited in a table (a.k.a Tabular Data™). Tables were not meant for layout.

Comment: You should have mentioned this is actually an email (where you sadly have no choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v got it to work! U used only one row and set background picture to it and then set my left and right on top of it, and set it with valing=top. Now it works evrywhere except in outlook :S

Answer (score 1):

I would convert this to use CSS instead.

Comment: i cant use css because i need to send it via email ... And there css won't work.